# Child element of modifier element?

Tags: html, css, bem

Take the following structure:

```
<div class='article article--yellow'>
  <div class='article__headline'>...</div>
</div>

<div class='article article--blue'>
  <div class='article__headline'>...</div>
</div>
```

If I need to make `article__headline` different for `--yellow` from `--blue`, should I do a CSS selector like:

`.article--yellow .article__headline { ... }`

Or, in the practice of minimizing selection-depth, is it valid BEM syntax to change the markup to this:

```
<div class='article article--yellow'>
  <div class='article--yellow__headline'>...</div>
</div>
```

Because then I could select it using only 1 selector: `article--yellow__headline`.

I know that technically it would work, but I can't figure out if this is valid according to BEM methodology or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a perfect question and [bem's faq actually answered it](http://getbem.com/faq/#block-modifier-affects-elements)!

> ## Can a block modifier affect elements?
>
> If I have a block modifier, for
>   example `xmas`, and I want the elements within that block to also be
>   `xmas` themed, how would it be best to do it.
>
> Does a `--xmas` suffix for every element seem necessary? Or would this
>   be the one use-case for nesting (e.g. `block--xmas block__elem { ...
>   }` ?
>
> However in general BEM recommends to avoid nested selectors, **this
>   is the case when they are reasonable.**
>
> When creating the nested selector, you declare that one entity depends
>   on another. As BEM introduces independent components, such an approach
>   is not suggested when we are speaking about 2 different blocks.
>
> But when it comes to a block and its element, they are not of
>   equivalent meaning. By it definition, an element does not make any
>   sense outside its parent block. So, an element is a block-dependent
>   entity. Assuming this, it is quite normal and logical that an element
>   is affected by the block's current state.
>
> So, this is quite a pattern in BEM to code
>
> ```
> .my-block--xmas .my-block__button {
>     /* Jingle bells, jingle bells, jingle all the way.*/ }
> ```

So the answer should be your first approach

```
.article--yellow .article__headline { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that two levels is too deep to assign specificity of `.article--yellow .article__headline`. Technically, `.article__headline` will never occur without an `.article--yellow` color modifier anyway.

Although the class names get lengthy, BEM allows you to easily-self document (assuming whoever comes after you understands these concepts too). Also, to me BEM components are not supposed to influence each other, [as detailed here](https://en.bem.info/method/solved-problems/#how-to-start-reusing-code-without-letting-components-influence-each-other).